# How to display bitmap resource vs. using shape drawing commands?

Tags: android, eclipse, bitmap, resources

How can I change my Bitmap from drawCircle into an imported image in drawable?

I have this code:

```
canvas.drawCircle((currentX * totalCellWidth)+(cellWidth/2),
    (currentY * totalCellHeight)+(cellWidth/2),
    (cellWidth*0.45f),ball);
```

...which produces this output:

[image]

I tried this change to substitute a bitmap resource for the circle:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

canvas.drawBitmap(b, (currentX * totalCellWidth)+(cellWidth/2),
        (currentY * totalCellHeight)+(cellWidth/2),
        ball);
```

...but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: tnx sir HostileFork for the revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to change the size of the bitmap.

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

// assign value for the new target size
int newsizeX = width;
int newsizeY = height;

resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resizedbitmap, width, height, true);

canvas.drawBitmap(resizedbitmap, *location in X*, *location in Y*, paint);
```

it should be working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your ic-launcher in your drawable folder? Because my ic-launcher bitmaps are in my drawable-hdpi/ldpi/mdpi/etc folders. If it is, try changing *R.**drawable**.ic_launcher* to *R.**drawable-hdpi/ldpi/mdpi/etc**.ic_launcher*

Comment: yes. the image is already there. my only problem now is how can I adjust the image size of the ic_launcher and make the size similar from the Circle. tnx for the help